# Cannot render my react app server side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, babel-cli

I am trying to render a basic react component via node js .

Unfortunately i got some errors. I think this is related to es6.

The problem is i already wrote a lot of code in es6 and now i want to render it in node js. I can't rewrite my entire app, so how to import my components and make them compatible witch node js.

What is what i've tried since now :

```js
const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html')
 fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData)=> {
  if(err){
   return res.status(404).end()
  }

  const app = renderToString(<ReactApp />)
  const RenderedApp = htmlData.replace('{{SSR}}',app)
  res.send(RenderedApp)
 })
```

I got this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

This is because ReactApp is a react component

i don't know how to import it on my node.

Any solutions ?

thanks

Comment: I don't really have any experience with server-side react but the error sounds like your JSX isn't being transpiled. If that's the case, it might be worth simply writing that line with ES5 react syntax and see if that fixes things.

Comment: @DonovanM . The problem is my react app is entirely written in es6 so i need a solution to transpile it without having to rewrite all the code. it will take me several days to do so. I need something else

Comment: Node will run ES6 fine without tranpilation, but yeah you'd still need all the JSX in your components transpiled. Have you added the react preset in your babel config?

Comment: @DonovanM yes i added react preset in `.babelrc` config still getting this error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` related to jsx tags in my imported react file

Comment: That is odd. I wish I could be of more help but I haven't really messed around with rendering react apps on the server, myself. I'm hoping someone will come through with an answer. It's probably something simple but not obvious.

Comment: Are you using Webpack? I had the same issue and what helped me was to disable `-p` switch from the build because of this. Disable production build and see if it works. If that doesn't help then please disable UglifyJs if you use it.